# xcel - native code to make text string of unknown length

Tags: excel

I'm trying to make a formula that takes account codes that will be listed in Column A and make a string of them, separated by "^."

E.g., If Column A has

```
A

1111

12345

2222
```

The result will be: `1111^12345^2222` as a single cell's entry

However, I don't always know ahead of time how many values will be in column A., And if there's only a few, I can't have the trailing ^^^^^^^^^^'s. Also, the account codes aren't always the same # of digits.

I have a rough version of it done with a ton of embedded If statements, but this is clunky. I also could probably do it via macro, but I'm trying to avoid. Is there a minimalist way to code this using native Excel functions, or should I just accept that I have to send out a macro-enabled workbook?

Comment: Why can't you just use `Concatenate`?

Comment: If i use something like:
=CONCATENATE(A2,"^",A3,"^",A4,"^",A5,"^",A6)

It will give me: 1111^^^^ if I only have one account code entered.   I could then use embedded IFs but this gets clunky. I'm trying to make it where somewhere between 10 an 50 account codes can be entered, as subsequent values in vertical cells in column A. And no matter how many values are entered, the result puts the carats in between.

Comment: I think I solved it with a helper column.

In column B I have added a formula that, for B1, is just the exact value in A1.
But then in B2, and dragged down is:  =CONCATENATE(B1,"^",A2)

And i can just pull this value from whatever row has the last entered account number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a VBA solution if you are interested:

```
Function Concat(rng As Range) As String

Dim i As Long
Dim iCount As Long

iCount = rng.Cells.Count

For i = 1 To iCount
    If Not i = iCount Then
        Concat = Concat & Cells(i, rng.Column) & "^"
    Else
        Concat = Concat & Cells(i, rng.Column)
    End If
Next i

i = 0
iCount = 0

End Function
```